# placements of an error message in while loop with conditional statements

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, break

This script checks for the existence of the file every 5 seconds for only 30 seconds.The script waits for the file to appear
If it finds the file it echos  “info: done waiting”.

The trouble I am having is with the error message after is exits
after 30 seconds if the file is not found.

The way the script is configured the now the error timeout is printed after each loop.

```
#!/bin/bash 
count=1 
while [ $count -le  6 ]
do
    if [ ! -e /tmp/2007.txt ]
    then
       echo "info : sleeping for 5 seconds"
       (( count++ ))
    sleep 5
    elsif [ -e /tmp/2007.txt ]
    echo "info: done waiting"
    break
    fi
echo "error: timeout"
done
```

This is what I get (bad)

```
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
error: timeout
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
error: timeout
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
error: timeout
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
error: timeout
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
error: timeout
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
error: timeout
```

if i place it out of the loop - it works great

```
break
    fi

done
echo "error: timeout"
```

This is what i get

```
casper_mint@casper-mint-dell ~ $ /tmp/wait_while 
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
error: timeout
casper_mint@casper-mint-dell ~ $
```

however if i touch the /tmp/2007.txt file - it breaks but the error timeout 
still shows up

```
casper_mint@casper-mint-dell ~ $ /tmp/wait_while
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
info : sleeping for 5 seconds
info: done waiting
error: timeout
```

This is an easy question, but i am bringing it here to the community because it reflects a common problem that i have in understanding loops with conditional statements and where to place those statements. I come across this alot in my scripting and I need to understand this, I need to evolve. All i am looking for is the script to check for 30 seconds, and if it does not find anything to throw out a error message. If the script finds the file, i want it to let me know and NOT kick out the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can check after the while loop whether the file was found or not before displaying the error message.

```
#!/bin/bash 

found=0
count=1 
while [ $count -le  6 ]
do
    if [ ! -e /tmp/2007.txt ]
    then
       echo "info : sleeping for 5 seconds"
       (( count++ ))
       sleep 5
    else
      echo "info: done waiting"
      found=1
      break
    fi
done

if [ ! $found ]
then
   echo "error: timeout"
fi
```

Comment: You can use arithmetic expressions for comparisions, like this: ``while (( count <= 6 ))``. Also you should not use ``[ ]`` if you're using bash, please prefer ``[[ ]]``.

Answer (score 0):

You only want the "timeout" message to be printed if the `while` loop "fails", that is, if the desired file is never found. You can use the following:

```
while (( ++count <= 6 ))
do
    if [ ! -e /tmp/2007.txt ]
    then
       echo "info : sleeping for 5 seconds"
       sleep 5
    elif [ -e /tmp/2007.txt ]; then
        echo "info: done waiting"
        break
    fi
    false
done || echo "error: timeout"
```

If `/tmp/2007.txt` is ever found, the last command in the loop to run will be the `echo` statement (or `[ -e /tmp/2007.txt ]`, if you removed the logging), which has a zero exit status. Otherwise, the last command to run is `false`, which always has a non-zero exit status, so the exit status of the loop will be non-zero as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the "while" loop check for the existence of the file, or make the "while" loop sleep for 30 seconds:

Make the "while" loop check for the existence of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
timed_out=false
while [ ! -e file ]; do
    echo "info : sleeping for 5 seconds"
    ((count++))
    sleep 5
    if [ $count -eq 6 ]; then
        timed_out=true
        break
    fi      
done
if $timed_out; then
    echo "error: timeout"
    exit 1      # error
else
    echo "info: done waiting"
    exit 0      # success
fi
```

Make the "while" loop sleep for 30 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash
timed_out=true
count=0
while [ $count -lt 6 ]; do
    if [ ! -e file ]; then
        echo "info : sleeping for 5 seconds"
        ((count++))
        sleep 5
    else
        timed_out=false
        break
    fi
done
if $timed_out; then
    echo "error: timeout"
    exit 1      # error
else
    echo "info: done waiting"
    exit 0      # success
fi
```